# C# webBrowser Can I change request Ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make an application user can use browser to go some links but when users request to link they going to use their own Ip I want to link to a web address with my server IP. Server going to request to link and show to the user website

Comment: You'll have to issue the request from your server, for example using HttpClient. You're essentialy becoming a proxy then.

Answer (score 0):

You can "spoof" IP changing headers like `IP`,  `X-Real-Ip` but you can't spoof the real IP of the request.

If you want to appear with the address of your server you need your server be a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) and route traffic from your WebBrowser thought this

Comment: I have an IP this IP can access some links I want to users can  access too with using accessible IP can you give some advice .how can I route traffic from your web browser

Comment: You need a proxy on your server, and in your APP's web browser have to connect to your proxy. Then the user's navigation is masqueraded with the server's IP. You also need to configure properly your proxy server. In fact, a proxy server could keep the original IP in the request headers.